# azure devops doesn't have permission on the agent to delete or copy

Tags: azure-devops

In azure devops we have hosted agent when I try to build using "ant" build the error I get is "BUILD FAILED
E:\x\work\sdm\sdm\build.xml:44: Unable to delete directory E:\X\work\sdm\sdm\Web\WEB-INF\classes\com\national\sdm"

ant and java path has been set in environment variables
java version "1.8.0_241"
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14

Seems azure devops doesn't have permission on agent to delete or copy
how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find it from other stack overflow page thanks to @Marina Liu "[VSTS build agent failed with get sources: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285359/vsts-build-agent-failed-with-get-sources-permission-denied)"

In services--> agent-->properties-->log on-->deselected from this account and selected "local account system"

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution [as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)